# Ball in closed convex set (from proof of open mapping thm)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, baire-category, open-map

(This is from the proof of the open mapping theorem, but this context isn't terribly important).

$B(X)$ means unit ball in $X$.

We have a bounded, linear, and surjective $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces. I have proved that $\overline{T(B(X))}$ contains ball $B_r(y)$. Now I want to exhibit a ball (with any radius) about the *origin* in $\overline{T(B(X))}$. I think this works:

- Set addition argument: note that
  $$B_{r}(0)\subseteq B_{r}(y)+\{-y\}\subseteq \overline{T(B(X))}+\overline{T(B(X))}\subseteq \overline{T(2B(X))}$$

This halves the radius and gives me $B_{r/2}(0)\subseteq\overline{T(B(X))}$ - fine. Can I avoid losing this constant by arguing from convexity? E.g.

- $B_r(y)\subseteq \overline{T(B(X))}$, so, as $T$ is linear and $B(X)$ symmetric about the origin, we have $B_r(-y)\subseteq\overline{T(B(X))}$. In fact, $\overline{T(B(X))}$ is convex, so we get $B_r(0)\subseteq \overline{T(B(X))}$.

Are both approaches valid?

Comment: I think the second argument should work. Concerning the first one, you’re using that $-y$ is in $\overline{T(B(X))}$ because it‘s symmetric, but then you can already use that also $B_r(-y)$ is in $\overline{T(B(X))}$ an go to the second argument, am I right?

Comment: @user768513 That's what I thought too. I am just a bit confused, because our lecturer presented a much more complicated argument, when it seems like the result follows from symmetry+convexity...